# Highcharts column and area chart, how to make area chart go to the edge?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a chart that is a column chart rendered on top of a area chart. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/78p42/4/

Is there a way to make the outer edge of the area chart to match up with the outer edges of the first and last columns in the column chart? In case you are not sure what I mean, please see this image I created.

[image: Example]

I figured there would be a way to do it in the plotOptions for the area charts, but I can't find a way.

```
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                pointPadding: 0.1,
                groupPadding: 0,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            area: {
                lineWidth: 0,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                pointPlacement: 0 // I have noticed that this will shift the whole graph over, but then there is a huge gap on one side of the graph
            }
        },
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've been fiddling with this for a few minutes using the pointPlacement option in both data objects. I'm not sure there's a clean way to do this with the Highcharts API.

Comment: @JamesHafner, my thoughts too, setting the column to `pointPlacement: 'on'` should get it close:  http://jsfiddle.net/78p42/5/

Comment: Thanks guys, pointPlacement: 'on' does get it pretty close!

Comment: In the pointPlacement you can also use number, which allows to adapt position with better precision.

Comment: That's true, but it actually shifts the whole series when you do that, which can look good with some datasets, but with others it can look pretty bad. Thanks for the comment.